# Displaying onclick events on tinymce

Tags: ajax, tinymce

Trying to get on click functions to display on my tinymce...any help will be much appreciated. still new to laravel...Have a feeling that ajax is supposed to be used but i dont know how to implement it. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
  <div class="panel-body">
                     <div  style="overflow-y: scroll; height:370px; background-color: #ffff">
                      @foreach($docs->titles as $title)
                        <ul>
                          <h2><li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction6()">{{$title->titlename}}</a></li></h2>
                          <ul>
                            @foreach($title->chapters as $chapter)
                           <h4><li>{{$chapter->chaptername}}</li></h4>
                           <!-- <li>{{$chapter->chaptertext}}</li> -->
                         @endforeach
                         <ul>
                           @foreach($title->parts as $part)
                            <h6><li>{{$part->partname}}</li></h6>
                            <!-- <li>{{$part->parttext}}</li> -->
                         @endforeach
                         <ul>
                            @foreach($title->sections as $section)
                            <h6><li>{{$section->sectionname}}</li></h6>
                            <!-- <li>{{$section->sectiontext}}</li> -->
                         @endforeach
                         <ul>
                            @foreach($title->subsections as $subsection)
                            <h6><li>{{$subsection->subsectionname}}</li></h6>
                            <!-- <li>{{$subsection->subsectiontext}}</li> -->
                         @endforeach
                         <ul>
                            @foreach($title->articles as $article)
                            <h6><li>{{$article->articlename}}</li></h6>
                            <!-- <li>{{$article->articletext}}</li> -->
                         @endforeach
                         </ul>
                         </ul>
                         </ul>
                         </ul>
                         </ul>
                        </ul>                       
                      @endforeach
                   </div>
                </div>
//this is my sample script i guess i didn't do it 
<script>
  function myFunction6()
  {
    var title = $(this);
    $('textarea#editor').html("asdasd");    
    console.log();
  }
</script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated...still new to laravel

Comment: I can't see a `<textarea id="editor"></textarea>` element in the HTML supplied. Is it missing entirely, or it wasn't included in this sample or ?

Comment: had omitted it. Sorry for that @DallasClark. the sample is as below. <textarea id="editor" name="editeddocument"class="form-control " rows="20" value="">
                        </textarea>